# While using IEEE access template and using pgfplots to draw graphs, document title and section headings are missing. What can be the issue?

Tags: pgfplots, titles

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}} 
\begin{document} 

\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}` `\author{\uppercase{First A. Author}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE}, \uppercase{Second B. Author\authorrefmark{2}, and Third C. Author, Jr}.\authorrefmark{3}, \IEEEmembership{Member, IEEE}} \tfootnote{This paragraph of the first footnote will contain support  information}

\corresp{Corresponding author: First A. Author (e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov).}

\begin{abstract} These instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for  IEEE Access.  
\end{abstract}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction} \label{sec:introduction} \PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{loglogaxis}\[xlabel=Cost,    ylabel=Error\] 
        \addplot\[color=red,mark=x\] coordinates {  
            (5,    8.31160034e-02)  
            (17,   2.54685628e-02)
            (49,   7.40715288e-03)
            (129,  2.10192154e-03)  
            (321,  5.87352989e-04)
            (769,  1.62269942e-04)  
            (1793, 4.44248889e-05)  
            (4097, 1.20714122e-05)  
            (9217, 3.26101452e-06) };

            \addplot\[color=blue,mark=*\] coordinates {     
            (15,    8.31160034e-02)     
            (20,   2.54685628e-02)  
            (59,   7.40715288e-03)  
            (149,  2.10192154e-03)  
            (371,  5.87352989e-04)  
            (799,  1.62269942e-04)  
            (1893, 4.44248889e-05)  
            (4997, 1.20714122e-05)  
            (9917, 3.26101452e-06)
                };

        \legend{Case 1,Case 2} 
    \end{loglogaxis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see a `\begin{document}` is that a typo? Make sure that your build doesn't have errors.

Comment: It wasn't formatted properly so you couldn't see \begin{document},  which I have corrected now. The file actually compiles but with pgfplots package, we are unable to see the title and section headings.